# Private Azure Kubernetes cluster with nginx ingress can't be restarted

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-load-balancer

I have private Azure Kubernetes cluster with installed Nginx Ingress (using internal Load Balancer)

This is non-production cluster and during weekends we plan stop it. But when we start it - it can't be finished successfully and after 30 minutes AKS cluster is in Failed state

After research I found that it happens only if Ingress is installed on private AKS with restricted outbound access

Any ideas how can it be solved?

Comment: what is your nginx and kubernetes version?

Comment: @HusseinSalman Kubernetes 1.24.6, Nginx 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is upgrade your Kubernetes cluster:

Check the upgrades available for your cluster

```
az aks get-upgrades --resource-group <resoure-group-name> --name <cluster-name> --output table
```

Then upgrade your cluster

```
az aks upgrade \
    --resource-group  <resoure-group-name> \
    --name <cluster-name> \
    --kubernetes-version <kubernetes_verion>
```

Replace the Kubernetes version by a version you got from the first command

Comment: When I run aks upgrade command have error response "Message: Operation is not allowed: Another operation (default - Starting) is in progress, please wait for it to finish before starting a new operation."